# Web Server Accessing DFS Share

Tags: asp-classic, vb6, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I'm using the following code in a VB6 DLL (Middleware on an ASP Classic Site) to create a drive mapping to a network share in order to copy files to and fro:

Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

ws.MapNetworkDrive strDrive, strPath, False, strUser, strPass

At the moment, this works if the share is a normal file server, e.g. \server\share\foo but if I move to a DFS namespace it no longer works, e.g. \mydomain.local\share\foo.

It works in the VB IDE (running as me but using same credentials as the service would) but once compiled and running under the web server the error returned is Error -2147023584 - A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

Most sites I have searched suggest the the local system policy "Network access: Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for network authentication" be disabled, this is already the case on my machine, I even enabled it then disabled it again to make sure.

Another site suggested connecting to the root node of the DFS first, that didn't work either.

(Windows 7, IIS 7.5)

Comment: is the user that executes the iis/app Pool a Domain user?

Comment: yes, the system can access network shares on a particular server no problem, it's just dfs ones that are the problem. The user it runs under does have access to the dfs share